# Java Kerberos ticket renew TGT

Tags: java, kerberos

I am using Krb5LoginModule in one of the POC. I have provided useDefaultCache=true and renewTGT=true.

The code throws an exception when the ticket is expired although I have mentioned renewTGT=true. I have set up allowtgtsessionkey value to 1 in windows registry (I am running XP SP2). The KDC (ActiveDirectory) settings are default. Ticket lifetime = 10 hours and renewal request threshold = 7 days.

### Source Code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule;

public class Temp3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");

        Subject subject = new Subject();

        Krb5LoginModule krb5 = new Krb5LoginModule();

        Map <String, String> map = new HashMap <String, String>();
        map.put("useTicketCache", "true");
        map.put("doNotPrompt", "true");
        map.put("renewTGT", "true");
        map.put("debug", "true");

        krb5.initialize(subject, null, null, map);
        krb5.login();
        krb5.commit();
        System.out.println(subject);
    }
}
```

The code works fine when the ticket is not expired i.e the time I ran kinit within 10 hours of running the code above.

I wrote this POC because I have to run JDBC based applications using SQL Server driver (version 4.0). I don't want long running services to fail during the database reconnect attempts which might occur due to factors such as network glitch resulting in broken pipe.

Comment: We have java based services (read TIBCO BusinessWorks) using SQL Server via JDBC Driver. DB team does not allow sql server authentication. We can't use integrated authentication since the java code will be running on AIX boxes. The option is to use kerberos. Given that these are long running services, I want to ensure that the ticket cache gets renewed when the connection is initiated i.e. when login is attempted. So the requirement is (1) use kinit initially and get a ticket cache (2) have mechanism to renew expirred cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going the wrong way. Fist of all you should use `LoginContext` to obtain credentials and not interact with Kerberos 5 directly. Second, non-human access needs a keytab. This is equivalent to a TGT. Export a Keytab for your server and modify the `Krb5LoginModule` configration. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html) tutorial will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As mentioned in the problem statement earlier, we will be using JDBC to connect to SQL server and all I have is JDBC URL 'jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<DB Name>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos'. I will not be able to provide LoginContext to this connection since the Krb5LoginModule will be invoked by SQL server JDBC driver. I will just be providing JAAS config file which will have settings for useTicketCache, renreTGT etc.

Comment: If you provide the JAAS config file you can put the KeytabLocation in there.

Comment: Here is my JAAS Login config content:client {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
 debug=true 
 useTicketCache=true 
 doNotPrompt=true
 renewTGT=true;
}; I am not using the keyTab. How can keyTab solve my problem - can you please shed some light on it? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Are you running under a system account? How is the initial TGT obtained? When you are running as `SYSTEM` there is a diffrent ticket compared to a regular user.

Comment: I am running it using a normal domain account for POC. The initial TGT is obtained by issuing java kinit. Apologies for delayed response, I wan not in office. Thanks for your continued support Michael-O.

Comment: Oh, this make a whole diffrence. I assumed that you where using the native windows credentials cache from LSA. If you perform a Java `kinit` you should rather export a keytab for that account or use the native Windows cache. A regular credentials cache is not intended to be used for machine access bur for humans only. Machines shall use keytabs only.

Comment: I tried with KeyTab as well but did not get success. Here is what I did (1)Exported keytab entries in a file using java ktab -a <service-user> command. I got the keytab file created in my user home. I am wondring how could I use this keytab to login (instead of using ticket cache). So in nutshell, in above code use map.put("useTicketCache", "false") and make the login successful. Would appreciate if you could provide a direction via some code snippet or a link that does so. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/index.html). The keytab has to be created by an admin.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this? "The keytab has to be created by an admin". I have created a keytab on my local machine logged in as a domain user and I do have admin permissions. Is that good enough?

Comment: Actually, yes. Now you need to configure that in your login module in jaas.conf/login.conf

Comment: All is working well now except I am not able to figure out correct way to point to keytab file from my jaas login conf. SQLJDBCDriver {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 principal=dtm53jh
 debug=true
 useTicketCache=false
 useKeyTab=true
 storeKey=true
 keytab=file:///C:/krb5.keytab
 isInitiator=true;
}; When I specify the keytab=file:///C:/krb5.keytab I get exception. When I remove this line and make krb5.keytab in my local user home all works well. Can you tell me what's wrong with the keytab file url and what is the correct format?

Comment: Use `keyTab="C:\krb5.keytab`. Protect the keytab with permissions too. Only your server process should have access to.