# Java Kerberos Renew TGT through Credential cache

Tags: java, kerberos

I am logging into Kerberos for making Oracle Database connection via Login context and Jaas config.
Kcc credential cache is being updated in the platform/Cloud separately. I have specified the parameters but the connections fails after the expiry 10 hours.
I have visited this link [Java Kerberos ticket renew TGT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242085/java-kerberos-ticket-renew-tgt). this does not solve my problem.

Jaas:

```
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useTicketCache=true
    doNotPrompt=true
    useKeyTab=false
    renewTGT=true
    refreshKrb5Config=true
    prinicpal ="aaa@xxx.xxx"
```

Stack Trace :
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed
to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredent
ial.java:147)

Comment: The Java implementation of Kerberos does not support renewable tickets, they have to be re-created periodically _(and BTW even renewable tickets have a limit on renewal where they must be recreated)_. So you have to either fork a thread in the background that periodically renews your ticket, or trap the error about ticket expiry and re-create it before retrying.

Comment: Erratum: since you consume a ticket that already exists in the cache, then you must find a way to "bounce" your JAAS config on expiry before retrying. Somehow.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter-  I am already re creating the ticket. but Data source is not aware of the refresh somehow.

Comment: what do u mean by bouncing the jaas?